# PXE boot fails With “Could not locate boot server.”

Tags: centos, dnsmasq, pxe

My target machine with PXE enabled receives a lease from dnsmasq and prints a message

```
UD: 192.168.10.123
```

which is the address of my dnsmasq/tftp server but then fails to get any further with "Could not locate boot server."

Here is my dnsmasq file.

```
port=0
domain-needed
bogus-priv
interface=eth1
listen-address=192.168.10.123
bind-interfaces
domain=chacha.mo
dhcp-range=eth1,192.168.10.200,192.168.10.207,255.255.255.0,8h
dhcp-option=3,192.168.10.1
dhcp-option=6,192.168.10.2
dhcp-option=42,192.168.10.1
enable-tftp
tftp-root=/var/lib/tftpboot
dhcp-boot=pxelinux.0
pxe-prompt="Press F8 for PXE Network boot.", 20
pxe-service=x86PC, "Install CentOS via PXE", pxelinux
```

I set up my CentOS 7.6.1810 install tree on a different server, @192.168.10.3. I have used this http install dist successfully using virt-install.

Here is my /var/lib/tftpboot/pxelinux.cfg/default file.

```
default menu.c32
prompt 0
timeout 300
ONTIMEOUT local

menu title ########## PXE Boot Menu ##########
label 1
menu label ^1) Install CentOS 7.6 x64 with Local Repo using Kickstart
kernel vmlinuz
append initrd=initrd.img inst.repo=http://192.168.10.3/pub/centos/7.6.1810/os/x86_64/  inst.ks=http://192.168.10.3/pub/kicker.ks inst.ks.sendmac
```

Started dnsmasq in the foreground. Saw no errors.

```
Jun  9 20:07:01 dnsmasq-dhcp[21523]: 577503379 available DHCP range: 192.168.10.200 -- 192.168.10.207
Jun  9 20:07:01 dnsmasq-dhcp[21523]: 577503379 vendor class: PXEClient:Arch:00000:UNDI:002001
Jun  9 20:07:01 dnsmasq-dhcp[21523]: 577503379 DHCPREQUEST(eth1) 192.168.10.202 00:1b:21:6c:00:93
Jun  9 20:07:01 dnsmasq-dhcp[21523]: 577503379 tags: eth1
Jun  9 20:07:01 dnsmasq-dhcp[21523]: 577503379 DHCPACK(eth1) 192.168.10.202 00:1b:21:6c:00:93
Jun  9 20:07:01 dnsmasq-dhcp[21523]: 577503379 requested options: 1:netmask, 2:time-offset, 3:router, 4, 5,
Jun  9 20:07:01 dnsmasq-dhcp[21523]: 577503379 requested options: 6:dns-server, 11, 12:hostname, 13:boot-file-size,
Jun  9 20:07:01 dnsmasq-dhcp[21523]: 577503379 requested options: 15:domain-name, 16:swap-server, 17:root-path,
Jun  9 20:07:01 dnsmasq-dhcp[21523]: 577503379 requested options: 18:extension-path, 22:max-datagram-reassembly,
Jun  9 20:07:01 dnsmasq-dhcp[21523]: 577503379 requested options: 23:default-ttl, 28:broadcast, 40:nis-domain,
Jun  9 20:07:01 dnsmasq-dhcp[21523]: 577503379 requested options: 41:nis-server, 42:ntp-server, 43:vendor-encap,
Jun  9 20:07:01 dnsmasq-dhcp[21523]: 577503379 requested options: 50:requested-address, 51:lease-time, 54:server-identifier,
Jun  9 20:07:01 dnsmasq-dhcp[21523]: 577503379 requested options: 58:T1, 59:T2, 60:vendor-class, 66:tftp-server,
Jun  9 20:07:01 dnsmasq-dhcp[21523]: 577503379 requested options: 67:bootfile-name, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132,
Jun  9 20:07:01 dnsmasq-dhcp[21523]: 577503379 requested options: 133, 134, 135
Jun  9 20:07:01 dnsmasq-dhcp[21523]: 577503379 next server: 192.168.10.123
Jun  9 20:07:01 dnsmasq-dhcp[21523]: 577503379 broadcast response
Jun  9 20:07:01 dnsmasq-dhcp[21523]: 577503379 sent size:  1 option: 53 message-type  5
Jun  9 20:07:01 dnsmasq-dhcp[21523]: 577503379 sent size:  4 option: 54 server-identifier  192.168.10.123
Jun  9 20:07:01 dnsmasq-dhcp[21523]: 577503379 sent size:  4 option: 51 lease-time  8h
Jun  9 20:07:01 dnsmasq-dhcp[21523]: 577503379 sent size: 11 option: 67 bootfile-name  pxelinux.0
Jun  9 20:07:01 dnsmasq-dhcp[21523]: 577503379 sent size:  4 option: 58 T1  4h
Jun  9 20:07:01 dnsmasq-dhcp[21523]: 577503379 sent size:  4 option: 59 T2  7h
Jun  9 20:07:01 dnsmasq-dhcp[21523]: 577503379 sent size:  4 option: 28 broadcast  192.168.10.255
Jun  9 20:07:01 dnsmasq-dhcp[21523]: 577503379 sent size:  7 option: 15 domain-name  chacha.mo
Jun  9 20:07:01 dnsmasq-dhcp[21523]: 577503379 sent size: 24 option:210   66:74:70:3a:2f:2f:31:39:32:2e:31:36:38:2e...
Jun  9 20:07:01 dnsmasq-dhcp[21523]: 577503379 sent size: 26 option:209   2f:76:61:72:2f:6c:69:62:2f:74:66:74:70:62...
Jun  9 20:07:01 dnsmasq-dhcp[21523]: 577503379 sent size:  4 option: 42 ntp-server  192.168.10.1
Jun  9 20:07:01 dnsmasq-dhcp[21523]: 577503379 sent size:  4 option:  6 dns-server  192.168.10.2
Jun  9 20:07:01 dnsmasq-dhcp[21523]: 577503379 sent size:  4 option:  3 router  192.168.10.1
Jun  9 20:07:01 dnsmasq-dhcp[21523]: 577503379 sent size:  4 option:  1 netmask  255.255.255.0
Jun  9 20:07:01 dnsmasq-dhcp[21523]: 577503379 sent size:  9 option: 60 vendor-class  50:58:45:43:6c:69:65:6e:74
Jun  9 20:07:01 dnsmasq-dhcp[21523]: 577503379 sent size: 17 option: 97 client-machine-id  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:1f:d0...
Jun  9 20:07:01 dnsmasq-dhcp[21523]: 577503379 sent size: 79 option: 43 vendor-encap  06:01:03:08:07:80:00:01:c0:a8:0a:7b:09:19...
```

Comment: Any luck?  I'm having this problem as well. :(

Answer (score 1):

In the DHCP protocol, there are two ways to specify the PXE boot filename and the TFTP server address to load it from:

- either using the legacy BOOTP fields (as DHCP is an extension of BOOTP)
- or using newer DHCP options for the same purpose.

Apparently `dnsmasq` uses the latter method by default... and I've encountered an otherwise quite modern PXE firmware that was slightly buggy in handling the newer-style options.

(If I recall correctly, it was a motherboard-integrated Intel NIC manufactured in 2011 or so. I think it added an extra 0x00 byte where it did not belong. If it's the same bug, you might see the PXE firmware trying to resolve "192.168.10.123\0" as a DNS name instead of properly using the IP address directly.)

Try adding this line to your `dnsmasq` configuration:

```
dhcp-no-override
```

It tells `dnsmasq` to use the older way, which is the "simple and safe" method according to `dnsmasq` man page.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on a centos8 build for a pxe-boot server... My issue turned out to be UDP ports were not open

[root@kickstart /]# firewall-cmd --add-port={4011/udp,69/udp} --permanent
success
[root@kickstart /]# firewall-cmd --reload
success

was my fix.